# Comparing performance of partition deletion vs recycle

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to compare performance of Partition recycle vs. Partition delete. I have flexibility in this code library to use either one, as the library abstracts whatever implementation on partition management done on the backend.

Here is my thought on one end:
Partition deletes look very simple and Cassandra manages it for us. If you are thinking about implementing partition recycle, 'might as well simply delete the partition and free to insert new ones as needed. Cassandra will physically delete the "tombed" partitions(1 tomb per partition sounds not bad) when compaction occurs.
Thus, at the high level, you have achieved "partition cycling", not recycling, but almost equivalent in performance, but simpler.

However, not too sure about this thought. How will this compare with partition recycle, where I maintain a "recycle bin" table then reuse partition IDs from this bin & do update to recycled partition(s) when persisting data. Sounds complicated than necessary, I really like the partition delete.

Any thoughts about this?
And yes, the library is a new concept in data management, scaleable objects persistence. Cassandra is just one of the backends that it can support, but it is what I am working on today to keep me busy while in between jobs. :)

Here is link to the project if you get curious, nothing big deal, 'just coding for fun, 'maybe useless code: https://github.com/SharedCode/sop

I have tried partition delete and it does not look bad at all. But wanted to know others' experience...

Comment: Partition tombstones are generated when an entire partition is deleted explicitly. This is the best route I'd recommend. I wanted to call out [a fantastic blog here](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html)  which explains the topic in greater depth.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking from a Cassandra perspective, it makes no sense to have to store data in a "recycle bin" because regardless of how many versions of a partition exists in the data files (SSTables), on the newest/latest version (based on write-time) will be returned when a table is queried.

If you need to update a partition, simply perform a CQL `INSERT` or `UPDATE` on it withOUT having to do a `DELETE`. There is no difference whether you do an INSERT or UPDATE because Cassandra does not do a read-before-write (with the exception of [lightweight transactions](https://www.datastax.com/blog/lightweight-transactions-cassandra-20)) -- Cassandra does not check if a partition exists in the table before doing an `UPDATE`, it just inserts the partition. Under-the-hood, all writes/mutations (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) are just inserts in Cassandra. Even for `DELETE`s, C* inserts a tombstone.

The only time you will need to issue a `DELETE` is when the partition is really no longer required. The idea that you need to temporary store the partition in a recycle bin is unnecessary. It won't solve any non-existent performance issue. Cheers!